# Filters with Django and jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I was trying to add some filters to a project that I'm currently working on to filter videos by year, genre, language, and quality:

year, language and quality filters work just fine so I removed their code.

When it comes to the genre I have a field in the model called tags which is a comma separated values. so for example, if the value is 'action, comedy, drama' and someone is looking for a genre of 'comedy' I want them to be able to find it from these tags.

Django code:

```
videos = Media.objects.order_by(
    '-date').filter(is_published=True)

if 'genre' in request.GET:
    genre_tags = request.GET['genre']
    if genre_tags:
        genre_tags = videos.filter(tags=genre_tags)

context = {
    'medias': paged_movies,
    'values': request.GET
}
return render(request, 'media_files/listing.html', context)
```

HTML code:

```
<select class="filter-genre">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option 
  {% if values.genre == 'action' %}
    selected
  {% endif %}
  value="action">Action</option>
  <option
  {% if values.genre == 'adventure' %}
    selected
  {% endif %}
  value="adventure"
  >Adventure</option>
  <option 
  {% if values.genre == 'animations' %}
    selected
  {% endif %}
  value="animations"
  >Animations</option>
  <option 
  {% if values.genre == 'crime' %}
    selected
  {% endif %}
  value="crime"
  >Crime</option>
  <option           
  {% if values.genre == 'horror' %}
    selected
  {% endif %}
  value="horror"
  >Horror</option>
  <option 
  {% if values.genre == 'documentary' %}
    selected
  {% endif %}
  value="documentary"
  >Documentary</option>
  <option 
  {% if values.genre == 'thriller' %}
    selected
  {% endif %}
  value="thriller">Thriller</option>
</select>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.filters form .filter-block select').change(function() {
  var e = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname,
    i = (new URL(e), $('.filter-language option:selected').val()),
    t = $('.filter-quality option:selected').val(),
    a = $('.filter-genre option:selected').val(),
    l = $('.filter-year option:selected').val();
  window.location.href = `${e}?lang=${i}&quality=${t}&genre=${a}&year=${l}`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"tags__contains"** while filtering, like this **videos.filter(tags__contains=genre_tags)**, this will check for containment of the specified value in the field but you have to make sure that tags match, for case insensitive match you can use **icontains** instead of **contains**